# Why do generic delegates have DelegateName<T>(T arg)? Why not DelegateName(T arg)

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

Why do generic delegates have `DelegateName<T>`? Why not `DelegateName(T arg)`

The argument already specifies the type, then why the delegate name has to be also followed by `<T>`, is it as naming convention, or is it for developer to know that it accepts integer or what is purpose of such C# syntax?

```
public delegate void MyGenericDelegate<T>(T arg);

Main()
{
    // Register targets.      
    MyGenericDelegate<string> strTarget = new MyGenericDelegate<string>(StringTarget);      
    strTarget("Some string data");  

    MyGenericDelegate<int> intTarget =  new MyGenericDelegate<int>(IntTarget);      
    intTarget(9);  

    static void StringTarget(string arg) 
    {      
        Console.WriteLine("arg in uppercase is: {0}", arg.ToUpper());  
    }  

    static void IntTarget(int arg)   
    {       
        Console.WriteLine("++arg is: {0}", ++arg); 
    }    
}
```

Comment: Why? Because that's the syntax of a generic thing...

Comment: What is the logical reason for it? Why not only Why not DelegateName(T arg)?

Comment: I think it's because you can define non-generic delegate with the same name (`public delegate void MyGenericDelegate(int arg);`).

Comment: I have the take on it that it was a deliberate decision. They only had 3 real options in order to create the ability to use <T>.  1.) Define a keyword for the type of the variable (another reserved word isn't really doing much good) 2.) Make the variable different (<T> arg) or 3.) Make the method different DelegateName<T>(....) So they had to make a choice there and choose that. The exact reasons I fear only their programmers really know (if it wasn't just a stomach feeling decision what felt better for them to use)

Comment: Short answer is to tell that `T` is a generic type not an actual type e.g. `public class T { }`

Comment: @tia from how I understand helloworlds question he knowss that but would like to know the exact reason behind why the syntax was chosen as it is.

Comment: I cannot read his mind, but as he keeps telling "Why not DelegateName(T arg)" so I assume he doesn't know that `DelegateName(T arg)` provides no hints that it is a generic declaration.

Comment: Also don't forget that you can write generic methods that use generic types in places other that the arguments and return types, so even if the syntax allowed you to specify the generic types via arguments and return values, you'd still in some cases need a way to specify generic types that aren't used for arguments and return values.

Comment: Hi Guys, suppose if I want to declare more than 1 param in the brackets, then should the angled brackets be updated to match the params brackets? public delegate void MyGenericDelegate<T,T>(T arg, T arg1);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A delegate is a class behind the scenes, and needs a type specifier to be generic.

You'll note how a declaration of a class like:

```
class MyList {
    T[] items; 
}
```

is invalid, because `T` is unknown in that context. Delegates need a type declaration for the same reason - `T` can't be resolved as a type.

---

Consider `public delegate void MyDel<T>(T arg);` - it may be interesting to examine what IL is emitted:

```
.class public auto ansi sealed ConsoleApplication20.MyDel`1<T>
    extends [mscorlib]System.MulticastDelegate
{
    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor (
            object 'object',
            native int 'method'
        ) runtime managed 
    {
    } // end of method MyDel`1::.ctor

    .method public hidebysig newslot virtual 
        instance void Invoke (
            !T arg
        ) runtime managed 
    {
    } // end of method MyDel`1::Invoke

    .method public hidebysig newslot virtual 
        instance class [mscorlib]System.IAsyncResult BeginInvoke (
            !T arg,
            class [mscorlib]System.AsyncCallback callback,
            object 'object'
        ) runtime managed 
    {
    } // end of method MyDel`1::BeginInvoke

    .method public hidebysig newslot virtual 
        instance void EndInvoke (
            class [mscorlib]System.IAsyncResult result
        ) runtime managed 
    {
    } // end of method MyDel`1::EndInvoke

} // end of class ConsoleApplication20.MyDel`1
```

Comment: Suppose if I want to declare more than 1 param in the brackets, then should the angled brackets be updated to match the params brackets? public delegate void MyGenericDelegate<T,T>(T arg, T arg1);?

Comment: Also, does the T has to be only one type, like int, then all int's.. or can we have int, string.

Comment: You can declare multiple type parameters, I.e. `Method<T, V>(T t, V v)` , and such a method could be passed two different types.

Comment: So whatever is in the angled brackets<>, should be strictly is same order as whatever is in () brackets. right?

Comment: No, it's not necessary they be in the same order.

Answer (score 7):

In order to declare the existence of the type parameter that you are using as the type of the argument `arg`, you need make your method generic. Making it generic entails using this syntax:

```
public delegate void MyGenericDelegate<T>(T arg);
```

Think about it: if you were to use this:

```
public delegate void MyGenericDelegate(T arg);
```

this declares a delegate type that literally accepts an argument of type `T`. The compiler will look at the current namespace and imported namespaces and try to find the type `T`, and if it doesn't find it, you'll get a compiler error.

Comment: Suppose if I want to declare more than 1 param in the brackets, then should the angled brackets be updated to match the params brackets? public delegate void MyGenericDelegate<T,T>(T arg, T arg1);?

Comment: Also, does the T has to be only one type, like int, then all int's.. or can we have int, string

Comment: @helloworld The more different generic types you want to deal with, the more type parameters you should have. If you have just one generic type to deal with, that is used in several places, you just need one generic type parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is you want to use strongly typed delegate. so basically either you use

```
public delegate void MyGenericDelegate2(object arg);
```

or

```
public delegate void MyGenericDelegate<T>(T arg);
```

you might want to look into generics more: [MSDN generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

Comment: Suppose if I want to declare more than 1 param in the brackets, then should the angled brackets be updated to match the params brackets? public delegate void MyGenericDelegate<T,T>(T arg, T arg1);?

Comment: Also, does the T has to be only one type, like int, then all int's.. or can we have int, string

Comment: It depends if you want same type of param or different. If same:
MyGenericDelegate<T>(T arg, T arg1);
if different MyGenericDelegate<T, U>(T arg, U arg1);
if one is known MyGenericDelegate<T>(T arg, string arg1);
if you want that T is only class MyGenericDelegate<T>(T arg, string arg1) where T:class; more one that https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx